# MySQL authentication using script without supplying password in plain text

Tags: mysql, bash, security, authentication, cgi

I have written a `CGI` script using `bash` which executes a `MySQL` query . Since my purpose is to automate a task , I had to put `MySQL credentials` in the script only with the password being in plain text . The issue for me is the server in question which will execute the script is a production server with outside access . I am looking for a solution where the automation remains but without supplying the password in plain text .

PS: One solution for me  is to enforce strict permissions by removing all permission for others,groups with rwx for root and ownership changed to root. But since this is a CGI script, I cannot remove read and execute permission for others.

The code is as follows

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""

echo "<html>"
echo "<body>"

mysql -h $host -u root -ptest -e "select User,marks,percent from $db;" | sed  's/\t/,/g' > /tmp/out.csv `

gnuplot gnudg.sh

echo "<img src="http://172.16.0.19/report/histreport.png" alt="DG-Reports">"

echo "</body>"
echo "</html>" `
```

Script permission:

```
ls -l /var/www/cgi-bin/ssdg/ssdgplot.sh
```

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1589 Apr 22 12:41 /var/www/cgi-bin/ssdg/ssdgplot.sh

Comment: Two questions:
do everyone who "executes" this script is safe to know the password ? or not ?
and the person with whome you want to hide password logs in as root?

Comment: The script is a CGI program and is executed whenever the weblink pointing to the script is clicked . The weblink is accessible on Internet. Also except root other users are not trusted to know the password. –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mysql you can use option file read from [reference1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/option-files.html), [reference2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-file-options.html) 
You can set values like username and password

```
[db-details]
user=username
password=password
```

and read this file for logging in to db in script.
and to avoid anyone else read it except root, just the permissions as

```
chmod 600 option_file
```

Comment: Thanks. Implementation details is also available here http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/1001956